# How to work-around AppleScript <<format of disk>> command working from within Script Editor but failing when saved as an .app?

Tags: applescript

The following script works as desired when run in the AppleScript editor but not when exported as .app and run directly.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fld to choose folder with prompt "Choose a volume" default location ("/Volumes")
    set n to name of fld
    set f to format of fld
    display dialog n & " is formatted as " & f
end tell

(*
When run from Script Editor result is:
   Macbook HD is formatted as Mac OS Extended format

When run from a compiled app result is:
   Macbook HD is formatted as «constant ****dfh+»
*)
```

I'm running OS X 10.11.6 (15G22010). Fixes or work-arounds welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Mac OS Extended format` is an enumerated constant (actually in integer value). It cannot be accessed outside of a `Finder` tell block and in an app the `display dialog` line is apparently treated as being outside the tell block. You have to coerce the enumeration to text.

I suggest this code, it uses the `disk` class of `System Events` and lists the disks

```
set theVolumes to list folder "/Volumes"
set chosenVolume to choose from list theVolumes with prompt "Select a volume"
if chosenVolume is false then return
set chosenVolume to item 1 of chosenVolume

tell application "System Events" to set volumeFormat to (format of disk chosenVolume as text)
display dialog chosenVolume & " is formatted as " & volumeFormat
```

**Edit:** The code above doesn't work apparently due to a bug.

This is an alternative with a little help from AppleScriptObjC and the Foundation framework

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

use framework "Foundation"

set theVolumes to list folder "/Volumes"
set chosenVolume to choose from list theVolumes with prompt "Select a volume"
if chosenVolume is false then return
set chosenVolume to item 1 of chosenVolume

tell application "System Events" to set volumeURL to URL of disk chosenVolume
set theURL to current application's NSURL's alloc()'s initWithString:volumeURL
set {success, theFormat, theError} to theURL's getResourceValue:(reference) forKey:(current application's NSURLVolumeLocalizedFormatDescriptionKey) |error|:(reference)
if success then
    display dialog chosenVolume & " is formatted as " & (theFormat as text)
else
    display dialog theError's localizedDescription() as text
end if
```

Comment: I cut and pasted your code but got the same result - works in AppleScript editor but fails when run as an application.

Comment: That's rather impossible. The enumeration is coerced to string in the `System Events` line.

Comment: The perhaps there is something corrupted in my machine. Just did it again to be sure in a fresh AS window, saving under a fresh name but same result - as an app I still get the «constant ****dfh+» output.

Comment: You're right. Same here. I regard this as a bug. I'm using Script Debugger and the variable is clearly indicated as text.

Comment: Your revised script works fine in the AS editor but when I try to export it as an app I get an error dialog: The document "test2.scpt" could not be exported as "test2.app". C and ObjC pointers cannot be saved in scripts. Compiling the script will reset property values and may resolve this issue.

Needless to say, I don't know how to compile the script, assuming it even solves the problem. :-(

I think my simplest solution is simply to have some sort of if ... then...else if ... else test for all the possible values.

Comment: @BruceH, You need to compile the script just before you save it as an application. Click the hammer icon in the toolbar or Command-K on the keyboard or Script Editor > Script > Compile.  BTW vadian's second script as an app does work as intended. +1

Comment: On the standard keyboard press Enter on the num pad to compile the script.

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much for your help vadian, and for the compile tip user34... It's all working now.